# How to change the language in single-user mode to English

Tags: virtualbox, lubuntu, single-user, russian

I have this problem: when I start single-user mode, the keyboard layout is Russian. I'm trying to change it to English using the keyboard shortcut ctrl+shift, super+space. Nothing comes out. How do I change the layout to English? I have a Lubuntu system. In VirtualBox. The main operating system is windows 10.[how it looks like[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38Rbi.png)

Comment: Do you need the Russian layout? If not, i.e. using only US (International) keyboard, then you can and should remove it. Problem solved.

Comment: I need Russian and English layouts. I speak Russian.

Comment: Runlevel 1 is a basic system administration level that is used to fix problems using the original language chosen at install. if you want to have multi-language setup, all existing tools assume you're using a higher runlevel (ie. the system is fully booted; rather than the partial-fix mode).

Comment: Hello, I didn't quite understand what I should do. Could you describe the sequence of actions. I looked at the runlevel0-6 module files and all files with an index greater than 1 conflict with the single-user target. But here's the trouble, the Russian keyboard layout I have not only for a single-user goal, but also for a multi-user goal. And files with an index greater than 1 are dependent on the multiuser target